# NetworkX: Graph alteration and restoration

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I have a multigraph with a number of nodes and edges. I preform a random removal of x number of nodes and calculate the Global Efficiency (GE) of the graph post-removal.

I would like to remove nodes in bunches and test Global Efficiency each time and generate a file which has the amount of nodes removed and the subsequent GE, for example:

```
5% removed GE: 1
10% removed GE: 0.4
15% removed GE: 0.34
...
```

In effect, I would like to restore the graph to its original state before the next iteration of node removal. I would like this, because the node removal is random in nature. Thus, after I remove 5% of the nodes and test GE, I would like the graph and then remove a random 10% which may contain a subset of the original 5% removed.

My attempts:

I have attempted to create a global variable which holds my original graph.

```
MG = nx.multigraph # load MG with the nodes and edges
global originalgraph 
originalgraph = MG

# conduct removal of 5% using MG
# . . .
# . . .


MG = originalgraph

# conduct removal of 10% using MG
# . . .
```

Result:

The first iteration works perfectly, 5% of nodes are removed. The second iteration seems to fail to restore MG to it's original state.

**Is there a way to store a NetworkX graph globally?**

Comment: Assignment doesn't create a copy; `MG` and `originalgraph` are two names referencing the same object.

Comment: How big is your original graph? If it doesn't take much time to pickle it in, one simple way is to pickle in your original graph at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Store the graph at a common reference `original_graph` and use [`deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to create a copy of the original unmodified graph to conduct further tests on.

```
original_graph = nx.multigraph # load MG with the nodes and edges
global original_graph # <--- I do not know why you need this unless you are accessing the original_graph from inside a function.
MG = original_graph.deepcopy()

# conduct removal of 5% using MG
# . . .
# . . .


MG = original_graph.deepcopy()

# conduct removal of 10% using MG
# . . .
# . . .
```

The problem with your approach was that both `MG` and `original_graph` had been pointing to the same graph object. Hence when you made a change to the graph you were not able to revert back to the unmodified graph **since there was only one graph object with multiple variables holding reference to the same object**. So when you modified, you essentially modified the only copy of the graph object.

Now when you perform [`deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) you essentially create an identical copy of the graph object referenced by `original_graph` and assign reference to the newly created object to the `MG` on which you perform the operations. Now by performing another `deepcopy()` you could create another copy of the `original_graph` and store its reference in `MG` for further tests all without modifying the contents of the `original_graph`.

Hope this helps.